# Why is componentWillUnmount firing after next components componentWillMount?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-v4

I have a React/Redux application with two components. I need to clear a portion of redux state when the first component unmounts, because the second component will error with the state in that form. I've tried to dispatch an action clearing the chunk of state when the first component unmounts, but the second component begins mounting before the first components `componentWillUnmount` method is called. When I view dispatched actions in redux-logger, I see the second component dispatching actions from `componentWillMount` and then `componentWillUnmount` actions from the previous component called.

This is not the expected behavior is it? I am also using react-router v4. Thanks!

Comment: `Avoid introducing any side-effects or subscriptions in this method. For those use cases, use componentDidMount() instead.` https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount

Comment: Ditto about using `didUpdate()` instead of `willMount()`. Also, given the question, it can be helpful if you say *what* you want to achieve with that, and why. Why does the second component crash? Can't you just not pass it that part of the state?

Comment: @sissonb thanks for your response but that did not help. after changing the second component to use componentDidMount instead of componentWillMount I still see the second component dispatching actions in componentWillMount before the first components componentWillUnmount actions are dispatched

Comment: @cfraser both components are connected to the "prospects" state. the first component is an index view of prospects and the second is a show view. when the second component mounts it loads a single prospect into the 'prospects' state and this view is dependent on just one prospect being there. Aside from this example i am looking for a standard way of cleaning up after myself before components mount. thanks!

Comment: I mean, redux state should simple store every data your app has. If there are many `prospects` in the state, when mapping the state to props in components, you only pass the one `prospect` you need, or all of them. Can you update your questions with the props being passed and `mapStateToProps` being used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Since React v16](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11106), the `componentWillUnmount` hook can fire asynchronously.

This means that you can't make any assumptions about the order (or timings) of the invocations of these hooks cross-component.